# how getHeight() works in java especially in paintComponent

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent, jcomponent

When I google this method. It shows that it returns the height of the current component. I got confused because when I use this getHeight() in public void paintComponent(Graphics g) it returns the value that I do not know where it came from. I am wondering is there any default height or width for paintComponent? Thank you. You can see the code below.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    // Find the maximum value in the data
    double max = data[0];
    for (int i=1; i<data.length; i++)
        max = Math.max(max, data[i]);

    int barWidth = (int)((getWidth() - 10.0) / data.length - 10);
    int maxBarHeight = getHeight() - 30;

    g.drawLine(5, getHeight() - 10, getWidth() - 5, getHeight() - 10);

    int x = 15;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        g.setColor(colors[i % colors.length]);
        int newHeight = (int)(maxBarHeight * data[i] / max);
        int y = getHeight() - 10 - newHeight;
        g.fillRect(x, y, barWidth, newHeight);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawString(dataName[i], x, y - 7);
        x += barWidth + 10;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am wondering is there any default height or width for paintComponent?

Yes, `0x0`.

`getHeight` will return the component's height as set by `setBounds`, `setHeight` or `setSize` (or typically `0` if it's not been set).

These are typically called by the underlying layout manager of the container in which the component has been added. The layout manager may use values from `getPreferred/Minimum/MaximumSize` to make determinations about how the component should be laid out and apply the values (size and position) it deems based on it's implementation

See [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details